# How to fix autoheight of datagridrow with wrapping textbox?

Tags: silverlight, datagridview, autosize

We have a datagrid with several datagridcolumn specified in XAML and one of the columns is a message column which can contains very long messages so we want the content to be wrapped.
This wasn't so hard to get setup using a DataGridTemplateColumn with a textbox as its content.

The following is the problem:

We allow the user to resize the columns by dragging its width. If the width gets larger the wrapped text will begin to unwrap if the column get wide enough. If the column shrinks the text wrapps more and more.

The problem is that the height of the row expands if the text wrapps which is fine but the row doesn't reduce its height if the column gets wider and the text unwrapps.

The following is the column definition, the grid doesn't really have anything special setup

```
<data:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Message" Width="*">
  <data:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap"
                 Text="{Binding MessageContent}" 
                 VerticalAlignment="Center">
      </TextBlock>
    </DataTemplate>
  </data:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</data:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

So what can I do to make the grid behave, I want the rows to autoadjust to the content of the rows both when the content gets higher and smaller.